# Are SQL unit tests supposed to be so long?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, best-practices, unit-test, tsqlt

I am writing stored procedures with some non-trivial business logic. I am trying to unit test them, but the actual tests end up being quite long (shorter ones starting at 40-50 LoCs, using commonly 4 different tables), which doesn't seem very "unit". (Admittedly, I format my code in a way where it takes a lot of space.)

In context of "normal" programming languages I've heard the advice to refactor the complex procedure into smaller chunks. But I don't want to do that here because:

1. I don't want to pollute  "global namespace" by small routines called from one place only.
2. Passing around tables from and to stored procedures is cumbersome.
3. Custom functions can have negative effects on performance.

Am I wrong about this reasoning?
I am new to unit testing, so perhaps I am just writing my tests wrong?
Is SQL longwinded language and thus it's unit tests are longer as well?

---

(I am using SQL Server with tSQLt framework, but I believe the question is system-agnostic.)

Comment: More compöex the alghorithsm get, more time unit testing you must speNd. but if you have split upthe hile thing into units, you havn't ti test them all again if you nedd some changes, so in the long run it gets quicker

Comment: @nbk I can see why it would be that way in general, however I am not entirely convinced it fully applies to SQL for the reasons mentioned in question.

Comment: Last time I looked, SQL wasn't a "programming language".

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille : I am not really sure what you react to. However, if you think the question could by improved by clearing terminological inaccuracies, please, do so.

Comment: big query you split also up to get at every step the correct data, stored procdures are the same a loop can be broken done to the first lopp only, a inser tSelct and so on are also separate parts, all parts combined form the result. it ios basically that what you do in all languages, from machine code to java

Comment: @GerardH.Pille From Wikipedia "SQL ... is a domain-specific language used in programming and designed for managing data held in ...  an RDBMS" - if it's not a programming language, then what is it? Also [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Declarative_languages) - it's in a list of programming languages. What would you call it, if not a programming language?

Comment: @Vérace, I would call it a Query Language, I wonder where I got that idea.  Anything procedural (wikipedia: it also includes procedural elements) is always via extensions that are different languages.  The programming language used by the OP is probably T-SQL, but he doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Gerard H. Pille "_The programming language used by the OP is probably T-SQL_" You're right, but I believe other... SQL "dialects"(?) work similarly enough to not matter for the purpose of my question. Am I wrong? What term would you suggest using instead?

Comment: Pay no attention @GerardH.Pille comment, whether something is a programming language or not is subjective (and some people take hard stances on the matter). I could argue just as easily that calling **SQL** a **Query Language** is too general and can be confused with **DQL (Data Query Language)** which would be incorrect to define it as, since that doesn't account for **DML (Data Manipulation Language)** and **DDL (Data Definition Language)**, etc, which are all under the umbrella of pure **SQL**. Debating on what's a programming language is a moot point since it's subjective; I even read...

Comment: ... something the other day that stated **object oriented programming languages** are not **procedural languages**. I think the lines are a little blurred and it's a silly thing to debate.

Comment: That aside, I've looked into tSQLt a while ago but haven't used it. But from my experiences writing T-SQL, C#, and Unit Tests in general, I don't see why T-SQL would have units that are any more verbose than C#. In fact, my unit tests in C# usually tended to be only a handful of lines of code (call it roughly 20 max), because they tested one specific *unit of work*. Your T-SQL unit tests should follow the same pattern. Perhaps you find yourself setting too many things up prior to the test, in T-SQL?...and if so there's probably a way to simplify / refactor without creating a bunch of small...

Comment: ... stored procedures. If you provided an example of one of your unit tests (with some comments), we probably could help you simplify it.

Comment: @J.D. : Yes, I have quite a lot of setting up context and environment in my unit tests. I considered moving some of it into setup method, however A) different tests sometimes require different setups B) I do need IDs of inserted fake records to work with them in the unit test. (I'm sorry, but rather not share the concrete code, since I do not have explicit permission to do so from my boss.)

Comment: @IvanLoginov Just anonymize the code, it's no different than sharing an anonymized execution plan. Without knowing where you're spinning your wheels, we won't be able to offer much advice on how to be more efficient. For example, if you run a series of unit tests sequentially that depend on the same **local TempTable** and you're recreating that **local TempTable** in each unit test, that's potentially refactorable since you can access the same **local TempTable** across **stored procedures** since the scope of a **local TempTable** is within the session that created it. I find a lot of...

Comment: ...people don't realize that, among other similar things, and cause themselves more work than necessary. Of course I couldn't advise on your specific situation without seeing some example code though, but I'm sure there's a few similar ways you can optimize how you write your unit tests.

Comment: @ J.D. : I added some example. The thing with the local TempTable is interesting idea, however wouldn't you want such TempTable right inside the unit test so that you know what is inside?

Comment: unit tests should be so fast that it doesn't matter if you run them.

Comment: @IvanLoginov Sorry I didn't get notified for your last comment (I think you accidentally added a space between the @ sign and my name). Thanks for the example, I'll take a look when I get a chance and will see if there's anything specific I can advise on to simplify / refactor. Regarding your last question, it depends on your situation, but as LowlyDBA mentioned, it's ok to break away from the patterns of procedural language **unit testing** when working with SQL, just because they are different in nature. Personally if I wasn't mutating the **TempTable** in my **unit tests** and I was...

Comment: ...using it for multiple tests, then I would definitely refactor it and only generate it once for the entire series of tests, to keep the tests lean and clean. Even in procedural languages like Angular / TypeScript's **unit testing**, you usually have a dedicated section of code that generates your variables / objects and refactors that logic in one place as opposed to doing that work in each **unit test**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong about this reasoning? I am new to unit testing, so perhaps I am just writing my tests wrong? Is SQL longwinded language and thus it's unit tests are longer as well?

I think this is a great (though somewhat opinion-based) question. The past few years I've attempted to implement tSQLt unit testing in a personal OSS project (https://dba-multitool.org/) to attempt to answer it via real world application. Unit testing for any type of SQL definitely breaks from classic norms and patterns. My tests definitely don't feel like unit tests and are usually more complex/longer than I'd prefer, but they have saved me a bunch of times from introducing breaking changes.

The stored procedures in my example are quite complex and long, so I came to a similar impasse as you: should I suck it up and deal with very complex "unit" tests, or fundamentally modify how the stored procedure works so that it is more amicable to unit testing in general? As with many database questions, the ultimate answer, I believe, is *it depends.* Performance and maintainability take a front seat here, in my experience.

I found that I wasn't able to justify largely changing the complex stored procedures to benefit from unit testing - adding more objects, as you noted, can increase complexity and in this case I was wary of asking end users to house a bunch of single-use objects in their database instead of offering an all-in-one utility stored procedure.

One technique that I did come up with was using optional parameters to induce test cases better. For example, I have parameters `@IsExpress`, `@SqlMajorVersion`, and `@SqlMinorVersion` that end users **should not use** (they are fetched at runtime if not passed) but that my [tests utilize](https://github.com/LowlyDBA/dba-multitool/blob/master/tests/sp_sizeoptimiser.Tests.sql#L148) to make sure I'm catching errors I want around unsupported versions. Adding a lot of errors will increase the overall reliability of the code without having to necessarily explicitly test the more complex logic areas that may be hard/not reasonable to do. This marginally affects the stored procedure's length and complexity, but lets me easily isolate functionality and reliably test for it. You could take this further and use parameters to trigger select portions of the stored procedure that need testing the most, or to achieve better code coverage percentages by avoiding a messy area that isn't worth covering or is out of scope.

With this approach I was able to get a fairly [high code coverage percentage](https://app.codecov.io/gh/LowlyDBA/dba-multitool) (98%+) and while I definitely don't test **all functionality**, I know that almost all of the code gets executed, errors when I need it to, and will parse on execution.

To close with a quote, [Wikipedia has unit testing defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) (emphasis mine):

> In computer programming, unit testing is a software testing method by which individual units of source code—sets of one or more computer program modules together with associated control data, usage procedures, and operating procedures—are tested to **determine whether they are fit for use**.

I won't say that Wikipedia (or the book being quoted by Wikipedia) is the end-all for technical definitions, but I do like this definition since it focuses on the end goal of unit testing, which I think tSQLt can reasonably achieve.

Besides, some unit tests are better than none and having lines of code that *aren't* covered by unit testing defined may be very valuable in the future. To expand on the latter:

In 3 years, you've left the company and Employee #948 is trying to address a bug in the stored procedure. They look and see that only lines 50-65 out of 300 aren't covered by a unit test, otherwise all other functionality has been tested. They now have a pretty good shot at spending time on a likely problematic area rather than reverse engineering the entire 300 lines. Or, the next intern/new hire can be asked to fill in missing unit test coverage gaps as a learning exercise. Knowing what you aren't testing yet can help prioritize future work and diagnose problems faster.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! "_having lines of code that aren't covered by unit testing defined may be very valuable_" Could you elaborate on this point? I am having trouble imagining such scenario

Comment: In 3 years, you've left the company and Employee #948 is trying to address a bug in the stored procedure. They look and see that **only** lines 50-65 out of 300 aren't covered by a unit test, otherwise all other functionality has been tested. They now have a pretty good shot at spending time on a likely problematic area rather than reverse engineering the entire 300 lines. Or, the next intern/new hire can be asked to fill in missing unit test coverage gaps as a learning exercise. Knowing what you aren't testing yet can help prioritize future work and diagnose problems faster.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is not a simple thing.  If an application will need maintenance, it will benefit the quality of the product by filtering out most errors before being handed over to the end user.  The advantage of automatic testing, and testing tout court, is very often ignored.

"In context of "normal" programming languages I've heard the advice to refactor the complex procedure into smaller chunks."
This advice is almost as old as programming.  If you don't follow it, you can as well shoot yourself in the foot using your preferred programming language
[shoot-self-in-foot](http://www.toodarkpark.org/computers/humor/shoot-self-in-foot.html).  But, and I quote: "you can't do foot_shooting in SQL."